# How to manipulate text lines and Create two separate files for odd and even

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

How to manipulate text lines and Create two separate files for odd and even ?

file 1:

```
iitmc01n01
iitmc01n03
.
.
iitmc01n71
```

file 2:

```
iitmc01n02
iitmc01n04
.
.
iitmc01n72
```

Comment: Sorry file 1:- odd number's and file 2:- even numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say

```
awk '/[13579]$/ { print > "file1"; next } { print > "file2" }' inputfile
```

This will print lines in `inputfile` that end with 1, 3, 5, 7, or 9 to `file1` and all others to `file2`.

Comment: Or just  `awk '{print > "file"(/[13579]$/?"1":"2")}' file`

Comment: I don't consider that clearer, to be honest. But sure, it'll also work.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
awk '{print > ("file"(substr($1,length($1))%2?"1":"2"))}' input
```

The  `%2` is used on last digit to see if number are odd or even

Added some more parentheses, thanks to info from Ed